# Accessing Nested elements in a JSON array

Tags: json

How would I access the value **label** in the following JSON array

```
 [ { _id: 596e0053e405e523bca7d289,
'[{"type":"button","label":"Button","subtype":"button","className":"btn-
 default btn","name":"button-1500381266064","style":"de
 fault"}]': '' },
 { _id: 596e0053e405e523bca7d28a } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your JSON is name of a property,Given that GUID is provided as string this should work:

```js
var t=[ { _id: '596e0053e405e523bca7d289',
'[{"type":"button","label":"Button","subtype":"button","className":"btn-default btn","name":"button-1500381266064","style":"default"}]': '' },{ _id: '596e0053e405e523bca7d28a' } ]

function propName(prop, value){
   for(var i in prop) {
       if (prop[i] == value){
            return i;
       }
   }
   return false;
}


console.log(JSON.parse(propName(t[0], ""))[0].label)
```

Comment: so my array is not in the JSON format then? sorry I am very new to this. I am printing this output in JADE pre-processor

Comment: data provided in your question is not an object nor array. If GUIDs are marked as string then we obtain valid array, which however has a property name as a JSON string( which parsed is an array with your desired object and property) with value "".

Comment: Thanks for your help, however this isnt exactly what I am looking for. Never the less I appreciate your help and the time invested.

Comment: I was able to obtain the data in the correct JSON format by including content type in my AJAX call. Thank you for all the help!